# Postgres optimize query on long table with big records

Tags: postgresql

I have a 150M row table with 4 columns:
- id (pk int)
- data (jsonb)
- created_at (timestamp)
- updated_at (timestamp)

It here are records over 4MB in size and EL tools we are using are not functioning properly. I need to find out the max record size, but the simple pg_column_size query pretty much pegged the CPU at 100% for over an hour before I stopped it. I can’t leave it like that for an undetermined amount of time because another system needs to use the database

Are there any ways to break the query up?  I hate the idea of using a cursor, but perhaps I should iterate over the pk. I’m looking for a set based solution.

Comment: You are saying *the* CPU - do you have a single core? If not, what's the problem with one of them being hogged by the query?

Comment: Try casting the column to text before measuring: `SELECT pg_column_size(thejason::text) FROM the_table;` [It reports 1 char fewer]

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe they tell me it has only 1 vCPU (it's on AWS RDS).  I am not the system owner (just saying).

Comment: Then it is simple: have the owner buy another core temporarily.